# Fixed 8 columns to 100% width in html table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I know this a simple question but still I'm a little bit confused.

This is regarding my HTML table. I want to make my columns 1 through 8 (`<th>`..) to be fixed only to 100% width or 100% HTML width view, and the rest of the column from column 9 and so forth, which is generated dynamically to be scrollable horizontally.

For example, if I have a 9 column table, when I load my page the column 1 to column 8 would be visible and the 9th column can only be seen when I scroll horizontally.

I already use `tale-layout:fixed;` but still it doesn't fit the column 1 to column 8 to 100% of my page. If there were 10 columns, it seems OK but if there's a lot of columns (like 15) that's when my column 1 to column 8 shrink and fail to obey my CSS width value.

Any advice?

Comment: -1 not an actual question

Comment: I dont see why you say that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lose the 'table-layout:fixed;'.

**using JQuery:**
on document ready, get the body outer width (with margin), divide it by 8, and inject the result to the 8 first colomns width (pixel based).

the browser will do the rest for you.
I would recomend enclosing the table in a wraper div, so the scrolling wont affect all the page.

Here is the complete solution (I did it with total:4, important:3 but you will need to alter that)

**HTML:**

```
<div id='Holder'>
<table id='Table'>
    <tr>
        <th id="0">Column Header</th>
        <th id="1">Column Header</th>
        <th id="2">Column Header</th>
        <th id="3">Column Header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some Text</td>
        <td>Some Text</td>
        <td>Some Text</td>
        <td>Some Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#Holder
{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var ImportantColumn = 3;
var TotalColumn = 4;

$(document).ready(function(){
var Width = $('body').outerWidth(true);
    for(var i=0; i< TotalColumn; i++)
        $('#'+i).width(Width/ImportantColumn);
    $('#Table').width((Width*TotalColumn)/ImportantColumn);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NVZmN/2/

if you want it to look cleaner, use this: (changes only in the CSS)
http://jsfiddle.net/NVZmN/3/

Comment: Jquery? It seems complicated but let me try.

Comment: Can you explain to me further what do you mean by these following "get the body width, divide it by 8, and inject the result to the 8 first colomns width (pixel based) the browser will do the rest for you". Sorry :(

Comment: Ok. i'm trying it now.. and its not as simple as i just said. if i'll come up with a solution, i will edit my answer.

Comment: OK. take a look now. it works.

Comment: Thanks  avrahamcool, it now works. :). I never though it can be done on jquery side.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make it so each column 1-8 has a width that adds up to 100%. When you have that, it'd fill up the whole page with your column 1-8, then make sure you apply

```
overflow:auto;
```

to each. If applying the overflow:auto to each doesn't work, trying applying it to just the 9th column.

You also may have to set each width to auto.

Comment: the problem with % based length, is that the columns will get length relative to the table length, so it will not be possile to give the first 8 a total of 100% while other column exists. the browser will ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do:

```
td {
  width : 12.5%
}
```

That should make all cells 1/8th of the total parent's width, even if there are more than 8 of them.

Comment: no, the browser will decrease the length of each column to fit the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely have to use a table?
Tables are supposed to be used for semantic data.

Regardless of the implementation though, the `overflow` CSS attribute is key.

If all that you want is a scrollable viewer, then I suggest using an ul.
With my implementation below, you will need to give the ul a fixed width, calculating the width of total number of li's width padding+margin.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bxAc/) example.  I hope it helps and gives you what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, I need to use a table. I have a lot of data at the next row, but i'm still stuck at this header thing "fixing the column width". because if i wont fix the column 1-8, say if i have 20 columns my table now will starting to shrink or compress on its own without following the css width that i set. i try overflow on the table but still doesnt work "<table overflow-x: auto; >". can help me advice to which part should i put the overflow thing?